# Creating Calculated Member in SSAS cube after renaming Dimension Attribute

Tags: ssas, mdx

I am very new to SSAS Cubes, and do not know MDX.

I need help in creating a calculated member. The dimension attribute that I am using in the calculated member calculation, is renamed, and that is why the calculation is not working.

I have a dimension named "**IN**" in the cube, and I am trying to count the **"CounterKey"** in the measures group when the value of attribute **"C 1"** in the **"IN"** dimension is 1.

I used the calculation below and it worked fine.

```
([Measures].[CounterKey count],([Dim IN].[C 1 Top Box].&[1]))
```

I had to rename **"C 1"** to a more user friendly/descriptive name i.e. **"Courtesy TB"**. After changing the name, I made the change in the calculated member as below as below

```
([Measures].[CounterKey count],([Dim IN].[Courtesy TB].&[1]))
```

but the calculation is not working any more, and I am just getting a null as a result.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you deploy and dimension rename change and process the cube? Or did you just deploy the MDX script only using BIDS Helper?

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is the wrong renaming or something else. Try to drag'n'drop the member from your cube and insert into the formula. Will the following return the null?

```
[Dim IN].[C 1 Top Box].&[1].UniqueName
```

If null, it means the member doesn't exist any more within a cube. It's a naming issue.